# Convert sentence into First order predicate logic.

Tags: artificial-intelligence

a) rabin likes only CSit Course
b)science course are hard.
c)all courses in CSIT are easy 
d)CSC 101 is a csit course.

Comment: a) Likes(rabin, CSit) $\land$ (Likes(rabin, x) $\implies$ x = CSit). Can you continue?

Comment: No can you help me solve it

Comment: You can do these in multiple ways. b) is probably something like this: TypeOfCourse(x)=Science $\implies$ Hard(x). M.SE is not really a homework site. You need to look at the pattern of these solutions, and do some work yourself. Otherwise, you learn nothing.

Comment: b) course(science, hard) is this answer correct ?

Comment: Well, that syntax makes "course" a predicate. You could work with that like this: (course(x) $\land$ type_of_course(x) = science) $\implies$ hard(x). You have to have a variable in this sort of expression, so you can quantify over it.

Comment: so we can write for c)    (course(x) ∧ type_of_course(x) = csit) ⟹ easy(x)  will this be correct ?   or (course(x) ∧ csit(x) ⟹ easy(x)

Comment: The first. Your second has an unclosed parenthesis.

Comment: for d) Vx: csc101(x) -----> CSIT(x,Course)  ? will this be correct sir?

Comment: Close. I would just do $\forall x:$ csc101(x) $\implies$ CSit(x). Remember what CSit(x) means: that the predicate CSit is true of x.

Comment: thank you sir . and the last question   *) Everyone's DNA is unique and is derived from their parents DNA ? into predicate logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, I'll write up the answers in the comments:
\begin{align*}
&a)\qquad (\forall\,x)[(\text{Likes}(\text{rabin},\text{CSit})\;\land\;\text{Likes}(\text{rabin},x))\implies x=\text{CSit}] \\
&b) \qquad (\forall\,x)[\text{TypeOfCourse}(x)=\text{Science}\implies\text{Hard}(x)] \\
&c)\qquad (\forall\,x)[(\text{Course}(x)\;\land\;\text{TypeOfCourse}(x)=\text{CSit})\implies\text{Easy}(x)] \\
&d)\qquad (\forall\,x)[\text{CSC101}(x)\implies\text{CSit}(x)] \\
&e)\qquad (\forall\,x)(\forall\,y)[(\text{DNA}(x)=\text{DNA}(y)\implies x=y)\;\land\;\text{Parent}(x,y) \implies\text{DNAIsDerivedFrom}(y,x)].
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you sir . and the last question *) Everyone's DNA is unique and is derived from their parents DNA ? into predicate logic?

Comment: That's tricky. You can see my solution.

Comment: so basically we are assuming DNA of x and y is equal in first line..  how about this        (∀x)(∀y):[ (child(x), parents(y) )  ∧ DNA=x=y  ----->  DNAIsDerivedFrom(x,y)]